# Nested Routes alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I am having some problems with nesting resources. I want to find out if there is a better way of doing things.

I have a to-do list application with three resources user, list and task. Each user has his/her own todo list.

My question is how else can i set up associations and routes to prevent me nesting three layer deep in my route file.

```
resources :users do
 resources :list do
  resources :task do
  end
 end
end
```

I want to prevent that. cheers

Comment: Can users access other user's lists?

Comment: No other users cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a user can only see her/his own lists and tasks, you don't have to nest these resources. Define them separately in your routes file:

```
resources :users

resources :lists do
  resources :tasks
end
```

And retrieve the current user from your authentication framework:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists = current_user.lists
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably duplicate for: 
[Rails 3 level deep nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661315/rails-3-level-deep-nested-resources)

Try experimenting with :shallow option:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do 
  resources :lists, shallow: true do
    resources :task
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't know how to title a search for such topic. What will the shallow option do and what changes if any will i have to make to the controller actions.