# Form for nested resource: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial, null

I'm doing an online tutorial and was tasked with implementing a comment resource that is nested under a post resource, which in turn is under a topic resource.  I've figured out all of the steps of the exercise except getting the 'comment create' form to show up on post#show.  I have been trying for several hours to fix it but keep getting the following error: `undefined method "model_name" for NilClass:Class`. I have no idea what it is referring to by `model_name` and in my desperation I even looked at the tutorial's code on GitHub, but I still can't see where I'm making the mistake.

My form is in a partial and the error points to the first line, so I'll paste that code here first:

```
<%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %> 
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8 %>
    </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'll post my routes so you can see the nesting:

```
X::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
    end
  end

  match "about" => 'welcome#about', via: :get

  root to: 'welcome#index'

end
```

Here is my Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.post = @post


    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error! Try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my post#show view (form should be rendering at the bottom):

```
<h1><%= markdown @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by 
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <br><br>    
    <p><%= image_tag(@post.image.url) if @post.image? %></p>
    <p><%= markdown @post.body %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <% if can? :edit, @post %>
      <%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_topic_post_path(@topic,@post), class: 'btn btn-small' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>  
<h4>Comments</h4>
<%= render @comments %>
<br>
<%= render :template => "/comments/_form.html.erb", locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
```

I would be SO grateful if anyone could help me with this problem.  And let me know if there's any info I should add.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Generally from what i have read its not recommended using 3 level nested resources. Could you link to the tutorial you are following?

Anyhow I would suggest using shallow on your routes instead.

```
resources :topics, shallow: true do 
  resources :posts, except: [:index], shallow: true do
    resources :comments, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

Will give you the following resources, which in return will make it easier to create correct forms in your view.

```
 post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)    comments#create
   topic_posts POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)     posts#create
new_topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/new(.:format) posts#new
     edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)             posts#edit
          post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#show
               PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#update
               PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#update
               DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                  posts#destroy
        topics GET    /topics(.:format)                     topics#index
               POST   /topics(.:format)                     topics#create
     new_topic GET    /topics/new(.:format)                 topics#new
    edit_topic GET    /topics/:id/edit(.:format)            topics#edit
         topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)                 topics#show
               PATCH  /topics/:id(.:format)                 topics#update
               PUT    /topics/:id(.:format)                 topics#update
               DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)                 topics#destroy
```

Now you should only have to send post_id to your comments form. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661315/rails-3-level-deep-nested-resources) I haven't worked much with 3 level nesting but this should give you an idea of how you could make it easier for yourself.

**EDIT:**
In the create action you should build the comment using @post and then set the user to current_user.

```
  def create

    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user


    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error! Try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And now no need for @topic

```
<%= render :template => "/comments/_form.html.erb", locals: { post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
```

Comment: So if I used those shallow options would I then use <%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %> and remove the topic variable declarations from CommentController?

Comment: Well, I feel pretty stupid but it turns out all I needed to do was add '@comment = Comment.new' to the "show" action of the PostController.  That had been defined only in the CommentController "create" action.

Answer (score 0):

Add '@comment = Comment.new' to the "show" action of the PostController. It had been defined only in the CommentController "create" action.